# C# Determinig if exception initialized with a message

Tags: c#, exception, constructor, try-catch, throw

Is there a way when catching an exception to determine if it were constructed with a non-default message.

```
        try
        {
            throw new Exception(message);      // case 1
            //throw new Exception();           // case 2
        }

        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            /* what do I put here such that if the case 2 exception were
               caught it would output exp.ToString() instead of exp.Message? */

            textBox1.Text = exp.Message;  // case 1 handeling

        }
```

Just to clarify when Exception(message) is thrown I want it to ouptut exp.Message and when Exception() is thrown I want to output exp.ToString().  I would prefer to accomplish this without adding a custom exception.  Thanks.

Comment: In the example above if throw Exception() the value of exp.Message reads "Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check the message against a default exception

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  bool isDefaultMessage = e.Message == new Exception().Message;
}
```

**Update**

Difference types of Exception

```
catch (Exception e)
{
  bool isDefaultMessage = false;
  try
  {
     var x = (Exception) Activator.CreateInstance(e.GetType());
     isDefaultMessage = e.Message == x.Message;
  }
  catch (Exception) {} // cannot create default exception.
}
```

Comment: Which would look like `textBox1.Text = isDefaultMessage ? e.ToString() : e.Message;`. I like this approach.

Comment: What about for when the catch() block gets different types of exceptions with default messages like IndexOutOfRange or FileNotFound.

Comment: Updated answer with different types of exceptions.

Comment: The compiler complains when I type x.Message with 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Message' and no extension method "Message' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Oops, need to cast to an Exception; see the new code.